# How to call a method once every week using c#

Tags: c#

Can any one say, 'How to call a particular method once every week in C# console application'

Thank you.

Comment: "weekly once"? Surely that's contradictory. Or did you mean "once weekly" as in "once per week" (which is the same as "weekly", by the way).

Comment: Waqas, I was leaving it up to the OP to clarify but, if you're going to jump in and assume one way or the other, you should probably change the title as well :-)

Comment: You can use the windows task scheduler and schedule it to execute once every week.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to start the code from an external application, the Windows Task Scheduler is an option. It allows you to start an executable automatically.

Answer (score 1):

A console app feels like a fragile way of doing this. I suggest you separate the scheduling of the task from the task itself. Windows has built in scheduling support in the form of the Task Scheduler (completely different from its namesake in .Net TPL).

So build your console application and schedule it to be run weekly. If it needs to maintain state during the week then implement it as a Windows service that can keep running.

There is a nice wrapper on the Task Scheduler API here: https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/ so you could even configure the scheduled task from .Net.

Answer (score 0):

You've got multiple options.

The one I use is adding the application to the task scheduler. There you can specify the interval in wchich it should be executed.
The disadvantege of this method is that you cant have any other method executed in another interval unless you also add them to their own application.

The second option is using [System.Threading.Thread.Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
If you want to use it, just do something like:

```
while(true)
{
//execute a method
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000*60*60*24*7);
}
```

The disadvantage here is that you have to use threading if you want to execute other methods during the sleeptime.